# new to programming with the Valence API

Tags: desire2learn, valence

We have a web site here at the University of Arizona which shows status of systems by using red light and green light indicators. We want to add the ability to monitor the status of the Valence API as far as whether or not it is currently up and functional. Does anyone have any sample code written in javascript that would simply tell whether or not the API is functional or not? I have examined the Getting Started samples and while useful it is a bit overwhelming from a beginning Valence API developer . I don't need to pull anything from a specific user context I don't think so simply just pulling something that just tells me that Desire2Learn's Valence API is responding would probably be sufficient. Any pointers are hugely appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Jeff Bishop
University of Arizona

Comment: Note that you can only make a very small number of calls without a user context: you can request information about the back-end's API versions, and you can request a User ID/Key pair. All the really functional Learning Framework API calls _require_ you to have a User ID/Key pair to auth with: as a primary design principle behind the framework, all your calls get made in the context of an auth'd app and an auth'd user, as demonstrated by signatures sent on the call's query string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific "ping" API call. The Valence Learning Framework API is built into the LMS's web services core application layer, so if the LMS is up and function (and support for the API is properly configured), then you should be able to make API calls. That said, a standard call that every client application should make as part of its work life-cycle is to query the [API contracts that the back-end service has available](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/apiprop.html#get--d2l-api-versions-). You can actually make this call anonymously, without a User ID/Key pair for a particular user, so, in some cases, this call can serve as a heartbeat or ping (although we should also emphasize that using it purely as a heartbeat/ping call is probably not a great idea, as all you'll be doing is generating traffic you don't need).

Rather than try to regularly "check" if the Learning Framework API is "up", you should assume that it's an inherent property of the LMS being available: it's either available (when the LMS is up), or it's misconfigured. In either case, the problem won't be with the API itself, or fixable using API calls.

Your app designs should instead assume that the API is available for your use (given you have an ID/Key pair for an actual LMS user) and should gracefully cope with failure.

Comment: We already have tools that monitor services in place so I am wondering if doing a simple "Get Versions" API call would not be needed. I mean, is it safe to assume that if Valence is deployed on a D2L instance and D2L is up and functional for users that there wouldn't need to be a monitoring process for the API itself? I am just unclear if this strategy would be necessary at all. Any feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: I would say that API health is really measured by two things: (a) is the LMS itself up? If the LMS's web server is up, and the LMS itself is functionally available to online users, then the API is probably (at least capable of being) up, and (b) can a client app successfully get a user ID/Key pair for a user? That second question is often harder to determine, but it's really a one-time configuration issue: barring certain rare cases, it's really a "when the setup is good, it just works" thing. Mind you, if you change aspects of this config, then that can cause a regression to not working.